# How do I include SSL when testing a Django app

Tags: django, ssl, python-unittest

I'm doing integration tests and one of our vendors require we make requests from a secure server. When doing manual testing, I can accomplish this using

```
python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem
```

However, I don't know how to incorporate `runserver_plus` and the arguments when running Django `TestRunner()`.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'tests.test_settings_integration'
    django.setup()
    TestRunner = get_runner(settings)
    test_runner = TestRunner()
    failures = test_runner.run_tests(["tests.integration_tests"])
    sys.exit(bool(failures))
```

The `TestRunner()` does not appear to take arguments.

Comment: Are those tests supposed to hit a remote endpoint over SSL using those pem files for encrpytion?

Comment: Yes, calling out the authorize.net to get a token from the sandbox environment.

Comment: Not sure what that means. But anyway I think you should aim for setting up whatever HTTP library you are using to accept those pem file **inside** the test. Maybe a helper function for doing remote calls would be useful.